# (gksudo:2375): Gtk-Warning **:cannot open display:

Tags: 14.04, grub2, lubuntu, nano, gksudo

When i insert this: `gksudo nano /etc/default/grub`

it replies with this:

`(gksudo:(4 digit number, always different)): Gtk-Warning **:cannot onpen display:`

But if i type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` it opens the requested file in nano editor.
I've tried to use synaptic package manager to reinstall some stuff, but even after reboot it didn't solve the problem.

Purged the package `gksu` and reinstalled, problem still exists.

Searched some stuff but nothing appears about a desktop. I'm using a very very old one, with Lubuntu 14.04.03 32bit LTS. This happened after i changed `nomodeset` in GRUB, but i've already removed that and the problem still affects me.

Comment: Why are you using gksudo instead of plain sudo, since nano is going to need a terminal to run in anyway?

Comment: yes, i know sudo works well, but i still want to solve this.

Comment: So are you running this inside your Lubuntu desktop (using lxterminal?) Is DISPLAY unset (`echo $DISPLAY`)? FWIW, regardless of the error message, I don't think gksudo is going to work for a terminal-based editor like nano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to run `nano` in the terminal `gksudo` is the wrong command.

If you want to call up another terminal emulator in which to run `nano` the first thing you need to do is make a launcher

Using your example:

`gksudo "lxterminal --command "nano /etc/default/grub""`

The graphical frontend of `sudo` *launches* a terminal emulator, and then executes the command within that terminal.

Comment: Oh ok, got it. I was using `gksudo` because i was following the instructions from a website, i didn't even looked properly to what i was writting. Thanks!